C++ concept that allows empty curly braces
I want my templated function to accept a parameter pack composed of either predicates with specific parameters or empty curly braces(for backward compatibility reasons). This parameter pack needs to match to a concept.
How do I change my concept definition to allow that?
The current version is:
concept myconcept = std::predicate<std::remove_cvref_t<V>, int> || "what do I put here?"

When I pass empty curly braces to the function, compiler says:
"candidate template ignored: substitution failure: deduced incomplete pack <[my predicate 1], (no value), [my predicate 2]>..."

Where (no value) is empty curly braces.

can you show a complete example? I dont understand what you mean with empty curly braces, how this can be an element in a parameter pack, or why it would be needed for backwards compatibility

oh I think I got it. You mean a call like this foo({},{})  and you need types deduced from those empty braces

Yes. The call might look like foo({}, someFunc) and I need to be able to ignore the first parameter.

You are asking about a concept, but taking a step back, how does your (unconstrained) function template itself look or how did it look before your change? It isn't obvious how calling with a variadic number of braced arguments is supposed to work. What are the types of these parameters supposed to be?

The call to the function is supposed to be f(func1, {}, func2...) and I want to ignore any empty arguments inside that function.

@IlyaZhuravlev Could you change to a different placeholder like struct {} empty; empty, int 0 or std::nullptr_t nullptr?

Since {} isn't deducible, the old version must've had that possible for only a few arities, yes? And with a specific type? Can't you provide overloads with that type defaulted for those?

Unfortunately, you can't do this within a parameter pack.
You would need to be able to specify default types for elements of the parameter pack, because braced-init-lists are non-deduced contexts for parameters that are not std::initializer_list, a reference to one (possibly cv-qualified), or a reference to an array.
